# Why did my Ansible install task failed? cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied

Tags: git, ansible

My task

```
- name: fetch k3s ansible role from github
  delegate_to: localhost
  git:
    repo: https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s-ansible.git
    clone: true
    dest: "{{playbook_dir}}/../k3s-ansible"
```

I got error, `ansible-playbook install_dependencies.yml`

```
TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "OS release=jammy, OS version=22.04"
}

TASK [fetch k3s ansible role from github] ************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": ["/usr/bin/git", "fetch", "--tags", "origin"], "msg": "Failed to download remote objects and refs:  error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied\n"}

git pull
Already up to date.
```

Why?

Comment: You possibly did a checkout on that machine with a different user before.

Comment: I tried to change permissons chown -R miki .git/,I go tthe same.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε How to check that?

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε chmod 755 FETCH_HEAD,the same!

Comment: An easy fix, since the `git` module of Ansible is not doing pull but only clones: remove the _../k3s-ansible_ folder totally and re-run your playbook.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Take a look at repo, https://github.com/MilenkoMarkovic/k3s-kvm

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε I can not find ../k3s-ansible

Comment: Possibly, once again, because the checkout was done by another user, switch to an administrator to find it.